# Creating a column in one dataframe from another dataframe doesn't transfer missing rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli'], 'marks': [99, 98, 95, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4'])

data = {'salata': ['ntomata', 'tzatziki']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['rank3', 'rank5'])
```

[image]

[image]

What I want is to to copy the salata column from **df2** to **df1**.

```
df['salata'] = df2['salata']
```

However, it doesn't copy the missing row **rank5** to the **df1**

[image]

**Update:** Thank you for the answers.

What should I use in case the dataframes have different column multiindex levels?

For example:

```
data = {('Name','Here'): ['Tom', 'Jack', 'nick', 'juli'], ('marks','There'): [99, 98, 95, 90]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['rank1', 'rank2', 'rank3', 'rank4'])

df[('salata','-')] = df2['salata']
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
#all columns
df = df.combine_first(df2)
#only columns in list
#df = df.combine_first(df2[['salata']])
print (df)
       Name  marks    salata
rank1   Tom   99.0       NaN
rank2  Jack   98.0       NaN
rank3  nick   95.0   ntomata
rank4  juli   90.0       NaN
rank5   NaN    NaN  tzatziki
```

EDIT:

If there is `MultiIndex` first create `MultiIndex` in `df2`, e.g. by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[''], df2.columns])

df = df.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
                 Name marks
         salata  Here There
rank1       NaN   Tom  99.0
rank2       NaN  Jack  98.0
rank3   ntomata  nick  95.0
rank4       NaN  juli  90.0
rank5  tzatziki   NaN   NaN
```

Another solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid creating another dataframe, but if this is not possible, then I will mark your reply as the accepted answer. However, what is the difference between combine_first and concat?

Comment: @Thanasis - Concat join by outer join, here is possible use `pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)`, `combine_first` is used mainly for replace missing values from another DataFrame. Here working same.

Answer (score 0):

if your indexes are representative of your example then you can do an outer join :

```
df = df.join(df2,how='outer')

       Name  marks    salata
rank1   Tom   99.0       NaN
rank2  Jack   98.0       NaN
rank3  nick   95.0   ntomata
rank4  juli   90.0       NaN
rank5   NaN    NaN  tzatziki
```